# Dataguard replication on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, dataguard

Can i use Dataguard replication on SQL Server 2019 (or 2022)?

I have an application with several SQL Server databases containing realtime data, historical data, calculated data using realtime information, etc. Besides that, all the other applications use Oracle DB with realtime replica created by Oracle Dataguard.

Is it possible to configure Oracle Dataguard to create realtime DB replica of SQL Server database?

Comment: No. Data Guard is a transaction log replication technology that is specific to Oracle Databases; it cannot be used with SQL Server. For heterogenous RDBMS change data capture and data replication, consider Oracle GoldenGate:  https://www.oracle.com/integration/goldengate/, or possibly use a database link to query the SQL Server databases directly from Oracle using Oracle Database Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Data Guard is physical data block replication. It is native to Oracle only. You can not even replicate between different Oracle version. It is also master-slave replication where slave replica must be read-only.

What you're looking for is logical replication. You need a product like GoldenGate, Shareplex or any other CDC tool(Continuous Data Capture).